# One Table - Two Fields - Same value - T/SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Source:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTab (ID INT, Value INT, Value1 varchar(10), Value2 varchar(10), value_ INT, Value1_ varchar(10), Value2_ varchar(10), Value3_ varchar(10), Limit INT)
INSERT INTO #TempTab
SELECT 1, 1,'One','One',1,'One','One','Yes',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1,'One','One',1,'One','Two','No',2
```

Current query try:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    CA.Value3_
FROM
    #TempTab t1
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT 
            Value, 
            Value3_ 
        FROM 
            #TempTab t2
        WHERE
            t1.Value = t2.Value_ AND
            t1.Value1 = t2.Value1_ AND
            t1.Value2 = t2.Value2_ AND
            t1.Limit > 1
    ) CA

DROP TABLE #TempTab
```

Current output:

```
ID  Value3_
1   Yes
1   Yes
```

Desired output:

```
ID  Value3_
1   Yes
```

Goal:

I would like to return on the record (ID and Value3_) where Value, Value1, and Value2 match Value_, Value1_, and Value2_. With the current logic, I'm getting both records return. I want only the 1st record (ID = 1 and Value3_ = "Yes").

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is. Can you rephrase, please. Thanks

Comment: Do your two rows actually have the same `ID` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're comparing both of the lines to themselves. I assume you would like to find just the first row, but also the second line (t1) will match to the first line (t2) and that's the second result you get.

Not sure what you're doing, but you'll get that result just by using one table:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.Value3_
FROM
    #TempTab t1
where
     t1.Value = t1.Value_ AND
     t1.Value1 = t1.Value1_ AND
     t1.Value2 = t1.Value2_ AND
     t1.Limit > 1
```

Check this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ab34/3)

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm trying to do. Didn't know you could have WHERE clause in one table and equate two diff columns like this... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @JamesZ point, assuming that ID was idempotent in your original temp table, e.g. you meant this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTab (ID INT, Value INT, Value1 varchar(10), Value2 varchar(10), 
                       value_ INT,  Value1_ varchar(10), Value2_ varchar(10), 
                       Value3_ varchar(10), Limit INT)
INSERT INTO #TempTab
SELECT 1, 1,'One','One',1,'One','One','Yes',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1,'One','One',1,'One','Two','No',2;
```

a common way to eliminate bidirectional joins when using the same table is to use `>` for comparisons on the self-join against the primary key to eliminate the 'duplicated' half of the diagonal. Also note that if you are dealing with tables only (i.e. not a `FUNCTION`) that a `JOIN` will suffice instead of a `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    x.Value3_
FROM
    #TempTab t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            ID,
            Value,
            Value1_, 
            Value2_, 
            Value3_ 
        FROM 
            #TempTab t2
      ) x
    ON
        t1.Value = x.Value AND
        t1.Value1 = x.Value1_ AND
        t1.Value2 = x.Value2_ AND
        t1.Limit > 1
        AND t1.ID > x.ID;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/543)

Comment: Ahh, I see what you did. You made a subquery and joined outside... neat! Thanks a bunch.